# BIND 9 XML Statistics-channels build modification after server is already up and running

Tags: linux, redhat, bind, xml

Migrating away from BIND9 to Route53 and would prefer not to use the named.stats file for monitoring activity during the migration period. As such, I checked the current named.conf and verified no `statistics-channels` entry exists, so no http web page for monitoring based on xml channel.

My question is: Because the previous sysadmins that deployed these BIND servers (RHEL 6) did not build it using `./configure --with-libxml2` based on my checks here:

```
[root@XXXXX /]# ldconfig -p | grep libxml2
        libxml2.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libxml2.so.2
[root@XXXXX /]# ldconfig -p | grep libxml2-dev
[root@XXXXX /]# named -v
BIND 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.68.rc1.el6_10.11
[root@XXXXX /]#
```

I see that libxml2 is on the system, however, it does not show up in the output of `named -v` as is documented in `kb.isc.org`:

```
If you are having trouble getting the statistics server to function, check the output of named -V to ensure that BIND was configured with libxml2, e.g.:

$ named -V
BIND 9.9.1-P2 built with '--prefix=/usr/local/bind-9.9.1-P2' '--with-libxml2'
```

Another observation is that `libxml2-dev` is not on the system, not explicitly required for all installs, just on some systems.

So, does anyone know if can I modify the BIND software build after initial configuration in order to get https monitoring of statistics (I.e.; Install the libxml2-dev library and supposedly get the libxml2-dev package loaded into the BIND configuration) or would I have to do a completely new build to enable this functionality?